# C# Generic method type constraints for more than one generic type

Tags: c#, generics

If the title doesn't make sense, I am struggling to find the proper syntax for constraining the type I pass to the method, as well as the type I want back. So e.g. like this:

```
public async Task<TOutput> SubmitRequest<TInput, TOutput>(TInput request) 
                           where TInput : RequestBase, TOutput : ResponseBase
```

Obviously that syntax isn't correct. But I can't find the proper syntax for constraining both those types.

Comment: Just specify the `where` keyboard more than once: `where TInput : RequestBase where TOutput : ResponseBase`.

Comment: Thanks! I was so close, but didn't think you could write that without a comma or something between the clauses.